# Replace all characters in a string except the ones that exist in an array

Tags: javascript

I want to replace all characters, except the characters that exist in an array, in a string with `*` .

```
let myArr = ['a', 'f', 'g'];
string.replace(all characters except the ones existing in myArr, '*');
```

Is this somehow possible with plain javascript?

If not how about a variable?

```
let myLetter = 'b';
string,replace(all characters except myLetter, '*');
```

Comment: Get all '*' position element, replace all, and at the end replace the '*' again, or use regex as well

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could create a regular expression and exclude the given characters from replacing.

```js
var letters = ['a', 'f', 'g'],
    string = 'abcdefghi',
    result = string.replace(new RegExp(`[^${letters.join('')}]`, 'g'), '*');

console.log(result);
```

Comment: you should probably escape special characters before passing to regex

Answer (score 1):

The regular expression `[^afg]` matches any character that isn't one of those three letters. You can create a regexp dynamically from the array, and then replace that.

```js
let myArr = ['a', 'f', 'g'];
let re = new RegExp('[^' + myArr.join('') + ']', 'g');
let string = 'the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog';
console.log(string.replace(re, '*'));
```

Comment: @incapaz I think you will have to elaborate that to make your point. I don't get it.

Answer (score 1):

Another way and not working with Symbols but exactly performing as requested would be:

```
const inputString = "abcdefghijfgklmnop";
const allowedArray = ['a', 'f', 'g'];
let resultString;
```

**Using 'map' after spread operator and finally 'join' the array elements back to string**

```
resultString = [...inputString].map(ch => allowedArray.includes(ch) ? ch : "*").join("");
```

**Using 'reduce' after spread operator**

```
resultString = [...inputString].reduce((acc, ch) => acc + (allowedArray.includes(ch) ? ch : '*'));
```

*Converting the string to an array with [...inputString] can be replaced with Array.from(inputString) if the spread operator is not familiar.*

Answer (score 0):

If you know the characters, you could just use regex:

```
string.replace(/^[your characters]/g,'*')
```

Otherwise, you can convert it to an array and then operate on each character:

```
string.reduce((acc,c)=>acc + (noreplacechars.indexOf(c) > -1 ? c : '*'),'')
```

Answer (score 0):

without regexps:

```
const allowed = new Set(['a', 'f', 'g']);
input.split('').map(x => allowed.has(x) ? x : '*').join('')
```

```js
const input = "abcdefghijklmnop";
const allowed = new Set(['a', 'f', 'g']);
console.log(input.split('').map(x => allowed.has(x) ? x : '*').join(''));
```

```
input.split('')
```

can be replaced with

```
[...input]
```

in ES6

Answer (score 0):

Here's a non-regExp way that uses `Array.map()`

```js
let myArr = ['a', 'f', 'g'];
let string = 'the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog';

let result = Array.from(string).map(function(char){
  return myArr.indexOf(char) > -1 ? char : "-";
});

console.log(result.join(""));
```